# Python syntax error when running from bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I've got a Python script uploaded to a linux machine, which I need to be ran through a bash script. The script runs absolutely fine when I type "python test.py", and it outputs as expected. However when I run the bash script "bash runScript.sh" I get a syntax error.

My python script (It's dead simple):

```
with open ("TextFiles/10.10.10.10config.txt",'r') as f:
    print f
```

My bash script:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://10.10.10.10/config.txt -O /usr/bin/grabber/TextFiles/10.10.10.10config.txt
/usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/grabber/test.py
```

The error when I run the bash script states:

```
File "/usr/bin/grabber/test.py", line 1  

with open ("TextFiles/10.87.4.4channel_config.txt",'r') as f:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: What Python version exactly are you using? What is `/usr/bin/python2 --version` and what is `python --version` ?

Comment: python --version returns 2.7.6 but /usr/bin/python2 --version throws Unknown option: --
usage: /usr/bin/python2 [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off putting a hashbang at the top of your python script?

Comment: can you let us know what does `which python` return

Comment: which python >> /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: Thank you  user3012759!! I changed my bash to /usr/local/bin/python following your advice and the script executed properly!

Comment: Looks like you have a pre 2.6 version of python installed as the default python2. Try running `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"`. I recommend uninstalling all versions of python 2.x other than 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: change `python2` to `python2.7` in your script.

The reason, as mentioned in the comments, is that your `/usr/bin/python2` is linking to an old version of python in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Again and again.... I'll show you!

```
[server]$ /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -c "with open('test.py','r') as f: print 'OK'"
 OK
[server]$ /usr/local/bin/python2.5 -c "with open('test.py','r') as f: print 'OK'"
<string>:1: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
  File "<string>", line 1
    with open('test.py','r') as f: print 'OK'
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`with` can be used after python 2.6